# Ruby, checking if an item exists in an array using Regular expression

Tags: regex, ruby

I am attempting to search through an array of strings (new_string) and check if it includes any 'operators'

where am I going wrong?

```
def example
  operators = ["+", "-"]
  string = "+ hi"
  new_string = string.split(" ")
  if new_string.include? Regexp.union(operators)
    print "true"
  else
    print "false"
  end
end
```

Comment: You are asking whether an array of *strings* contains a specific *regexp*. Obviously, that will always be false, because your array *doesn't* contain regexps, it contains strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) instead, which takes a *pattern*:

```
pattern = Regexp.union(['+', '-']) #=> /\+|\-/

['foo', '+', 'bar'].any?(pattern) #=> true
```

But since you already have a string, you can skip the splitting and use [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#match-3F-method):

```
'foo + bar'.match?(pattern) #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You wish to determine if a string (`string`) contains at least one character in a given array of characters (`operators`). The fact that those characters are `'+'` and `'-'` is not relevant; the same methods would be used for any array of characters. There are many ways to do that. @Stefan gives one. Here are a few more. None of them mutate (modify) `string`.

```
string = "There is a + in this string"
operators = ["+", "-"]
```

The following is used in some calculations.

```
op_str = operators.join
  #=> "+-"
```

**#1**

```
r = /[#{ op_str }]/
  #=> /[+-]/ 
string.match?(r)
  #=> true
```

`[+-]` is a *character class*. It asserts that the string matches any character in the class.

**#2**

```
string.delete(op_str).size < string.size
  #=> true
```

See [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete).

**#3**

```
string.tr(op_str, '').size < string.size
  #=> true
```

See [String#tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-tr).

**#4**

```
string.count(op_str) > 0
  #=> true
```

See [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-count).

**#5**

```
(string.chars & operators).any?
  #=> true
```

See [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26).